# jquery autocomplete multislect backspace issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplete to  enable multiple values into a single field.
its works fine until i use backspace in input field.
when user make one or more selection each time id of selected filed is added to one hidden field.when user remove one or more selections using backspace i am not able to capture this event using autocomplete and because of that i am not able to modify the value of hidden field.

could you please help me out.
please refer to below link for more details.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z26yv/

html:

```
<label>Teams:</label>
<input type="text" id="teams" />
<br />
<br />
<label>Team IDs:</label>
<input id="team_ids" />
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                {label: "Choice1", value: "Choice1", db: 1},
                {label: "Choice2", value: "Choice2", db: 2},
                {label: "Choice3", value: "Choice3", db: 3},
                {label: "Choice4", value: "Choice4", db: 4},
                {label: "Choice5", value: "Choice5", db: 5},
                {label: "Choice6", value: "Choice6", db: 6},
                {label: "different text", value: "different text", db: 7},
            ];

            function split(val) {
                return val.split(/,\s*/);
            }

            function extractLast(term) {
                return split(term).pop();
            }

            $("#teams")
            //don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind("keydown", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function(request, response) {
                    //delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                },
                focus: function() {
                    //prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    //remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    //add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    //add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");

                    $('#team_ids').val($('#team_ids').val() + "," + ui.item.db);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```